# EKEvent eventIdentifier null xcode 9.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode9, titanium-mobile

I'm saving an event with XCode and it saves normally. The save returns an ID as well.

When I try to get all the events of my calendar, and then one by one I access the id of the events, it is always `nil`

Save Code:

```
-(NSNumber*) save:(id)arg 
{
    id val = nil;
    ENSURE_ARG_OR_NIL_AT_INDEX(val, arg, 0, NSNumber);
    EKSpan span = EKSpanThisEvent;
    if (val != nil) {
        span = [TiUtils intValue:val def:EKSpanThisEvent];
    }
    EKEventStore* ourStore = [module store];
    if (ourStore == NULL) {
        DebugLog(@"Could not save event, missing Event Store");
        return NUMBOOL(NO);
    }
    EKEvent* currEvent = [self event];
    if (currEvent == NULL) {
        DebugLog(@"event is missing");
        return NUMBOOL(NO);
    }
    __block NSError * error = nil;
    __block BOOL result;
    TiThreadPerformOnMainThread(^{
        result = [ourStore saveEvent:currEvent span:span commit:YES error:&error];
    }, YES);`enter code here`
    if (result == NO || error != nil) {
        [self throwException:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Failed to save event : %@",[TiUtils messageFromError:error]]
           subreason:nil
          location:CODELOCATION];
    }
    return NUMBOOL(result);
}
```

Retreive Code:

```
- (NSArray *)_fetchAllEventsbetweenDate:(NSDate *)date1 andDate:(NSDate *)date2
{
  if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
    __block id result = nil;
    TiThreadPerformOnMainThread(^{
      result = [[self _fetchAllEventsbetweenDate:date1 andDate:date2] retain];
    },
        YES);
    return [result autorelease];
  }
  EKEventStore *ourStore = [self ourStore];
  if (ourStore != nil) {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [ourStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:date1
                                                               endDate:date2
                                                             calendars:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[self calendar]]];
    return [ourStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: hi, did you figured out the reason for this, I am facing this issue in iOS 12. The calendar events particularly outlook events are not syncing.

Comment: having the same issue in iOS + outlook? any workaround?